# File uploader using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, ajaxform

I want to upload file using jQuery, but I am getting an exception saying `undefined is not a function` at `$('#myFile').ajaxForm({`

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="x.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/FileUploadUI5/upload"
        method="POST" id="myFile">
        <input type=file name=upfile><br> <input type="submit"
            name="Upload" value="Upload" id="ubutton" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**X.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#myFile').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend : function() {
            },
            uploadProgress : function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                alert(position + "|" + total + "|" + percentComplete);
            },
            complete : function(xhr) {
                // status.html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#ubutton').click(function(e) {
        $('#myFile').submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you include the JS file for this plugin correctly?

Comment: Is `x.js` your copy of the `AjaxForm` plugin?

Comment: I have included jquery nd in console i printed jQuery.fn.jquery; and result is "1.11.1" ... so i think it is correctly included

Comment: Also, you don't need ` $('#ubutton').click(...` as '#ubutton' is already a submit button inside '#myFile' form. And, why do you have an empty beforeSend function?

Comment: yes X.js is jqiery file ...  which i have downloaded from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: You also need to download and include the jquery form plugin from here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: My requirement like like on click of button I need to upload. I do not wan to do any processing before send so it is empty

Comment: can i do that without ajaxForm bcos i cannot include jquery form plugin

Comment: If you want to do an upload without the plugin you can do something like this - http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1766159

Answer (score -2):

I believe sending files is not available in pure jquery. I did it few days ago using plugins;
http://rubaxa.github.io/jquery.fileapi/
or
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

The first one is really impressive; i was able to do it in no time and visual progress indicatior and ability to use webcam for images is astonishing.

more in the topic You can find here, i think: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

hope it helps :-)